# Is Ninja Hattori a cartoon or anime?

Tags: ninja-hattori-kun

I've been watching this thing since I was 8, now I am curious to know what I've been watching all these years. I am not sure what makes an anime and a cartoon different, but I think anime has more violence content than cartoons.

In many of Ninja Hattori's episode, use of weapons, like sword and shuriken was shown. And in most of the episode you can see Hattori and Amada fighting, which is not suitable for a cartoon. Those fights can be compared to the fights in DBZ or other action manga and animes.

So what do you think, is it a cartoon for children or a action genre anime/manga?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What differentiates anime from regular cartoons?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/69/what-differentiates-anime-from-regular-cartoons)

Answer (score 3):

It's Anime because it's made in Japan, and (generally) made for Japanese people.

Cartoons are animations in a broader sense, and as such, Anime is a form of Cartoon.
Made in Japan.

http://myanimelist.net/anime/4936/Ninja_Hattori-kun

It lies in the rating of the show and its targeted audience to determine what can be shown to viewers, low violence doesn't make something a Cartoon if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ninja Hattori is an Anime series because it's Japanese series adopted from the Manga.
Anime comes from manga, and this is one reason that Anime users like to watch anime than cartoons. Ninja Hattori specialized to represent Ninja cultures and techniques using weapons things like swords and others.

Ninja Hattori also airing in several Asian countries like India, it's a popular show airing in English and other languages on Disney Channel.

Reference:
https://ninjahattori.fandom.com/wiki/Ninja_Hattori-kun_(anime)

Comment: Regarding “This series is also available on other countries' channels”, this point might be more relevant if you can [edit] your answer to include examples of anime-only channels in other countries that air(ed) *Ninja Hattori*.

Comment: Just for fun mostly but RE: Anime comes from manga, that's often true but such a definition is rather incomplete. Pokemon's anime isn't based on its manga, its based on its video game which both predate its manga. We also have many anime which are not based on manga like God of Highschool animated by Mappa which is based on a Korean Webtoon (Manhwa), Batman: Gotham Knight, Pingu in the City and even some Ghibli films like Tales from the Earthsea based on an American children's fantasy series and Howl's moving castle based on a British YA fantasy novel