# Is there any clarification from the publisher/author of Hunter x Hunter regarding the quality of chapters 335 to 338?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

Why do Hunter x Hunter's chapters between 334-338 look this bad?

I know that Togashi had several illnesses, but is the illness that he had getting worst at those chapter? (I didn't resize the image so everyone could see the picture very clearly at the first glance).

Has Shueisha ever made a clarification regarding those chapters?

I have the physical books/compendium version of Hunter x Hunter that have relevant chapters on it (chapter 335-338 are included in vol 32 of HxH). But the art is still the same (my physical books of HxH are translated to Indonesian language and it's published through legal sources).

It happened in the *13th Hunter Chairman Election Arc*, started on chapter 334. why the art suddenly/constantly changed?

**Page 19, chapter 334**

[image]

The audience looks are not drawn well, it looks like that scene was still a draft.

In **chapter 335**, it looks worse than **chapter 334**.

**Page 7, chapter 335**

[image: Page 7, chapter 335]

And worse in **chapter 336** (it looks like a rough sketch, look at Killua's hair and body, Nanika's inked hair, also the bench....)

**Page 12, chapter 336**

[image: Page 12, chapter 336]

The worst in **chapter 337** (What's wrong with you Kaito... and also the background... just what... )

**Page 12, chapter 337**

[image]

Well, chapter 337 is the worst that I have observed so far... They started to change the art frequently starting from chapter 338, but I would say, it's still bad.

**Page 12, chapter 338**

[image]

and finally, in chapter 340, we can have the fine art from Togashi.

**Page 17, chapter 340**

[image]

Comment: Are your images from the weekly manga or the compendium volumes?  When time pressure hits, Togashi's art will tend to suffer, as he does what he can to make delivery of his weekly art.  But when the HxH volume is published, he tends to clean it up so that it looks a lot more like his usual artwork.

Comment: @RichF i have the physical books/compendium volume of hunter x hunter that have relevant chapter on it (chapter 335-338 are included in vol 32 of hxh ). But the art is still same ( my physical books are translated in indonesia and it's legal sources )

Comment: Probably same reason with [Historie's rough sketch](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/39163/2869): the deadline. But it could also due to author's health condition or private matters.

Comment: http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2016/05/18/painful-trend-emerges-in-hunter-x-hunter-author-comments From what I've read over the years, Togashi doesn't like working with assistants and likes to complete his work himself. Chronic pain makes life miserable and personally it feels to me it has taken the joy out of his Manga. His work on YuYu Hakusho was of fairly consistent quality afaik. He also redrew a full volume worth of Manga chapters sometime back. Imho, he owes us nothing and the Manga should go on a hiatus rather than having both the Mangaka and fans struggle.

Comment: @Arcane he has an assistant, https://imgur.com/TPWTbHQ

Comment: @Gagantous I said "he doesn't like working with" not that "he doesn't have". To clarify he doesn't like leaving some stuff to the assistants that they can handle. Example: http://www.anime-now.com/entry/2017/09/12/230058 Here it is mentioned that although assistants were supposed to draw the backgrounds, Togashi started using simple lines for background rather than have assistants draw them. This leads him to a vicious cycle of overworking, sacrificing the manga quality and bitter fans

Comment: @Arcane "He Refused to Let His Assistants Do the Inking"  i see... and togashi said "If I did that… I think that’d be the end of my life as a manga creator" wow...

Comment: Also on SciFi.SE: [Why did the Hunter x Hunter manga quality randomly deteriorate?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15044)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(expansion to my comment above, which would have been an answer if I could have found the image below)
I said:

> Are your images from the weekly manga or the compendium volumes? When time pressure hits, Togashi's art will tend to suffer, as he does what he can to make delivery of his weekly art. But when the HxH volume is published, he tends to clean it up so that it looks a lot more like his usual artwork.  – RichF 5 hours ago

I can't identify the page, chapter, or volume, but here is an example image I built to answer a completely unrelated question ([What defines the art-style of Japanese manga?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/31114/what-defines-the-art-style-of-japanese-manga/38882#38882)):

[image: weekly and volume view of same HxH page]

On the left is Togashi's original page as it appeared in its weekly form.  On the right is his final version of the page which appeared in the associated volume.

Based on Gagantous' reply to my comment, apparently Togashi didn't always clean up sloppy weekly pages for the follow-up volume.  Maybe for the volume used in the Question to show us examples, Togashi's health (and/or deadline pressure) didn't allow for the cleanup.